# How to correctly escape single quotes in AWK

Tags: freebsd, sendmail, sed, awk

It isn't clear exactly what more needs to be escaped in the following macro to allow it to be used with awk or sed on FreeBSD.

```
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
```

Here is an awk command that attempts to insert the above line at line 90 below the `SMART_HOST` configuration.

```bash
awk 'NR==90 { print "define(\`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS\', \`TCP $h 2525\')dnl"}1' example.com.mc
```

The command results in the following error:

```
Unmatched '"'.
```

**Note to future editors**: the backtick/single quote is not a typo. This is an ancient quirk of the m4 language that is used to write the macros for Sendmail configuration: ["m4 uses single quotes (opening "`" and closing "'") to quote arguments"](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/contrib/sendmail/cf/README#:%7E:text=m4%20uses%20single%20quotes%20(opening%20%22%60%22%20and%20closing%20%22%27%22)%20to%20quote%0Aarguments)

**Additional Note**: Octal escapes don't seem to work when using `sed` on FreeBSD. In that situation, use the `xNN` escaped hexadecimal characters in that situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot escape single quotes as the command itself is surrounded by single quotes, but you could use an octal escape code `\047` to represent `'` in POSIX awk. Additionally, you could use a hexadecimal escape code `\x27` in GNU awk (`gawk`).

From [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), [3.2 Escape Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Escape-Sequences):

> `\nnn`
>
> The octal value `nnn`, where `nnn` stands for 1 to 3 digits between ‘0’
> and ‘7’. For example, the code for the ASCII ESC (escape) character is
> `\033`.
>
> `\xhh…`
>
> The hexadecimal value `hh`, where `hh` stands for a sequence of
> hexadecimal digits (‘0’–‘9’, and either ‘A’–‘F’ or ‘a’–‘f’). A maximum
> of two digits are allowed after the `\x`. Any further hexadecimal
> digits are treated as simple letters or numbers. (c.e.) (The `\x`
> escape sequence is not allowed in POSIX awk.)

```
awk 'NR==90 { print "define(\`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS\047, \`TCP $h 2525\047)dnl"}1' example.com.mc

gawk 'NR==90 { print "define(\`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS\x27, \`TCP $h 2525\x27)dnl"}1' example.com.mc
```

If you would like to also use `\140` (or `\x60`) to represent the *backtick*:

```
awk 'NR==90 { print "define(\140RELAY_MAILER_ARGS\047, \140TCP $h 2525\047)dnl"}1' example.com.mc

gawk 'NR==90 { print "define(\x60RELAY_MAILER_ARGS\x27, \x60TCP $h 2525\x27)dnl"}1' example.com.mc
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a subtle trick with Sendmail configuration macros. The first "quote" character is a backtick and the second is a single quote. I understand what the correct answer should be now and thank you so much!! However, I would adjust your answer so that it looks like this: `\140RELAY_MAILER_ARGS\047, \140TCP $h 2525\047`.

Comment: Thanks, I simply thought it was a typo. Updated my answer to cover this. Hope all the new examples are working as well.